# How do I make the popup menu that appears after you use a tool open at the cursor?

Tags: interface

In Blender 2.8+ when I execute a command such as extrude or bevel the property pop-up menu opens in the bottom left of the screen. Is there an option to set so that property pop-up menus open at the cursor?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Just press *F9* and it will show up on your cursor.

Comment: That worked, thank you.

Comment: Is there any way to make it permanent so that I don't have to always hit F9?  Like set that as a default?

Comment: I don't think that's possible currently (without add-ons), but this sounds like a great workflow improvement to implement. maybe submit to https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/